# Getting error (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY) when migrating from MS Access 2013 to SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, ms-access-2013, sql-server-2014

OK.... I've checked and rechecked Google, StackFault, Experts-Exchange, etc... for a resolution on this error and they all say to register the `DAO360.DLL` and add its path to the environment settings. I've done that several times and I still get the following error:

> Access Object Collector error: Database
>   Unable to cast COM object of type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.DBEngineClass' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao._DBEngine'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{00000021-0000-0010-8000-00AA006D2EA4}' failed due to the following error: Error loading type library/DLL. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY)).
>   An error occurred while loading database content.

I'm not using compression and this is a clean install of Windows 7 Enterprise x64, Office 2013 Pro Plus x64 and SQL Server 2014 Enterprise.

I am migrating from an 2013 .accdb to SQL 2014. I have tried previous versions as well. And I am using the migration wizard from SSMA 6.0.

What am I missing, overlooking, needing to do, etc...?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify: (1) Are you using the SQL Server Migration Assistant (SSMA) for Access, or are you "rolling your own" migration code? (2) Is the Access database an .accdb file or an .mdb file?

Comment: Launch SSMA for Access, then open Windows Task Manager and check the Processes tab. Do you see "SSMAforAccess.exe *32" or just "SSMAforAccess.exe"?